# Javascript event for SVG loaded in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg-animate

How can i attach a Onclick event handler to all SVG path element? I have loaded my SVG in an iframe. I tried to use the following but the click event is not firing.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        debugger;
        $('path').click(function () {                
            alert("Hello");
        });
}); 
<iframe id="frame" src="myFile.svg" border="0" width="100%" height="450px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#frame").contents().find("path").on("click", function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Events from within an `iframe` do not bubble through it to the containing document. So, if even possible to bind events this way, you need to find the `path` elements inside the `iframe` and bind `click` events to them.